# Magento security patch SUPEE-6482, What is patched?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Today 04.08.2015 there was a new security patch released, some colleagues and I were checking the patch, and is always nice to have some discussion about what changed, also does anyone know what are the possible attacks that could affect and unpatched shop? 
What 's the worst that could happen?

Update: I just wanted to add the email magento sent today to complete the post.
[image: Magento Email Update]

Comment: I am sure there will be a wrap-up these days. However, if you checked it already and want to have a discussion, go ahead! Share your thoughts and findings!

Comment: Does anybody know that this patch fix Blocks HTML output cache bug?

Comment: The patch itself, no. The full install for 1.9.2.1 would have to be examined for those changes, at this point it seems to only address 4 security issues

Comment: You will have to do a full upgrade, or backport 1.9.2.0 => CMS Block and Widget caching in `magento-1921/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php` and
`magento-1921/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Widget/Block.php`

Comment: I was sitting here trying to figure out how "3 hours ago" and "today" were April 8th, then I realized it was dd.mm.yyyy :P.

Comment: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html - I've just wondered when the next patch will come after there was so much focus on headers the last days. And there it is!

Comment: @hakre - I'd read the patch contents before including headers, unless those headers are actually in the API. The full download has some patches in the http controller and javascript cookie template, but the 6482 patch doesn't.

Comment: As this post currently appears on Google for people checking out this patch and looking for comfort that it doesn't destroy any of your hard work, I have just successfully patched a number of 1.9.1.0 and 1.9.2.0 sites and all was straight forward. Do take this opportunity to ensure you have your customer sites backed up and running in your dev environments with copies of their latest live databases and apply the patch on dev first so a) you know it will work and b) if you kill your customers site you have a working version at base as a reference. Another evening lost patching Magento but goes

Comment: Several Magento security patch released within the last few months. If I had no safety thought, I would wait a few weeks to group my updates with the potential new ones (and save some effort)!

Comment: Though not 100% related to the question, this may be interesting, too. I created a gist showing the diff of Magento 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.1 ignoring whitespace: https://gist.github.com/sprankhub/196a95fc3f1664f69f08 It was created via the following command: diff -rw magento1920 magento1921 By the way, it also shows that the static block caching bug has been solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The actual security patch (**SUPEE-6482**) only affects the two following files and is an API patch.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
```

The full 1.9.2.1 install is a different matter altogether. I would diff source code between 1.9.2.0 and 1.9.2.1 to figure out the other two items that were patched.

Release notes are for the full installer, you have to check the patch to see if it actually includes all the items noted in the release notes.

Implications of running an unpatched server:

1. Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers => **Cache Poisoning**
2. Autoloaded File Inclusion in Magento SOAP API => **Remote code autoload**
3. XSS in Gift Registry Search => **Cookie theft and user impersonation**
4. SSRF Vulnerability in WSDL File => **Internal server info leak and remote file inclusion**

**NOTE:** Files patched in the full install archive that are not patched with the patch, hmm?

```
diff -r magento-1920/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php magento-1921/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
300a301
>         $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
302,303c303,304
<             $host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
<             return $host[0];
---
>             $hostParts = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
>             $host =  $hostParts[0];
305c306,313
<         return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
---
> 
>         if (strpos($host, ',') !== false || strpos($host, ';') !== false) {
>             $response = new Zend_Controller_Response_Http();
>             $response->setHttpResponseCode(400)->sendHeaders();
>             exit();
>         }
> 
>         return $host;

diff -r magento-1920/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml magento-1921/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
37,38c37,38
< Mage.Cookies.path     = '<?php echo $this->getPath()?>';
< Mage.Cookies.domain   = '<?php echo $this->getDomain()?>';
---
> Mage.Cookies.path     = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->getPath()) ?>';
> Mage.Cookies.domain   = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->getDomain()) ?>';
```

Comment: I think the missing files fix the most critical "Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers" issue. The "XSS in Gift Registry Seaerch" issue seems to be mistakenly added to the patch documentation for the CE version, as the Gift Registry is an EE-only feature.

Comment: Yep, I figured that it was important enough to apply the missing changes to my CE installation anyway and not wait for Magento to figure it out and send us a V2 patch when they get around to it. Cache poisoning and unfiltered user input used in cookie components seems like a biggie.

Comment: Magento has updated the documentation: both the "Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers" and "XSS in Gift Registry Search" issues are marked as "For Magento Enterprise Edition Only". But in the meantime, Magento CE 1.9.2.1 does contain fixes for the "Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers" issue, or at least a part of it.

Comment: Heh, the CE short-change in action. CE doesn't have the Wishlist, but definitely needs the "Unvalidated Headers" issue to go away via patch, not documentation change. Oh, well... more of what we've come to expect.

Comment: **For the record - according to our tests - *Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers* is NOT a CE vulnerability.** If anyone can provide a POC that there is a CE vulnerability, please go to http://magento.com/security and report it.

Comment: Has this actually been tested with third party FPC modules so we know that for sure, or are we getting a Microsoft answer where we become the POC for some criminal? After all, where does my Amasty FPC get the Unvalidated Headers from, hmm? You're either not explaining this point well or else you're not thinking of the inheritance factor here. Just because EE has an FPC and you've cleaned up the act for it doesn't mean our customers are home free.

Comment: It seems there's 2 perspectives: One is the (legitimately) paranoid view to expect that your compromised unless proven otherwise.  Which I am, so I've tested the file shipped in 1.9.2.1 and it doesn't appear to break anything so we're deploying it.  The other is "it's the 3rd party vendor's responsibility to support their clients" which is not UNREASONABLE at least when Ben notes they're looking into the issue.  Magento now PAYS $$$ to those who report bugs w/ POC via bug bounty program, so  best choice seems to prove it exists rather than debate it here. Or am I totally missing something?

Comment: See also http://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/Magento-SUPEE-6482-partial-patch-released/m-p/12772 for a discussion on whether the "Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers" issue should be part of the patch or not.

Answer (score 9):

I hade a look at the changes in detail and which side effects are to expect.

In the version for EE 1.13.1.0 the following files changed:

```
2015-08-05 07:14:25 UTC | SUPEE-6482_EE_1.13.1.0 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v2 | 7e38036f94f250514fcc11d066a43c9bdb6a3723 | Tue Jul 28 14:29:35 2015 +0300 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 294 (offset 7 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftregistry/search/form.phtml
```

- In `Adapter/Soap.php`, urlencoding is added to authentication data. This should have no negative side effect. It ensure, that the resulting `wsdlUrl` is valid. Without this change, one could influence the URL
- `Product/Api/V2.php`: Here are some checks if passed data is an object. This should not happen under normal circumstances.
- in `Request/Http.php` and `PageCache/Model/Processor.php` a check is added when getting the HTTP HOST. This seems to cover the header injections mentioned. The check only applies if there is a `;` or `,` in the HTTP host, so this should be uncritical in real life systems / have no negative side effect.
- in the `cookie.phtml` escaping is added. So this has to be forward ported to your theme if you overwrite that file
- similar for `giftregistry/search/form.phtml`

To sum it up, I would say that applying the patch should not have any negative side effects. Remember to forward port the changes to your `.phtml` files.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, the header injection and cookie component escaping are easy to backport to CE.

Comment: No need to port. There are patch versions also for CE in the download area.

Answer (score 5):

Weird thing is that EE patch contains modifications on following files:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
```

When the CE one doesn't, for an equivalent version.

I presume there is something missing on that `SUPEE-6482` CE version, and a V2 could be released soon.

Comment: I thought the same thing!

Comment: Yes, you noticed right. That's what I got by diffing the 1.9.2.0 and 1.9.2.1 installation archives. I have a fully patched CE installation due to this, I went ahead and manually patched the two files mentioned. The js cookie file needs to be patched in your custom template as well if you have that file in it. They probably skipped the request controller as a patch for it would have to patch a previously patched file and we got no CE love going on.

Comment: One more reason to "wait" some days before to deploy on production environment (and use these days to do better checks before going live). Today, one more update notification in Magento Backend (just the notice about the 2 instead of 4 security vulnerability ). Anyway, I'll wait until monday for going live, at least.

Comment: Magento has updated their release note: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html 

Some patches are effectively EE only. But I still don't get why those 2 files, core based, are not concerned in CE patch, as they are integrated in the CE 1.9.2.1...

Answer (score 4):

Please read Magento's documentation on this release, the answer is there: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.1.html

Comment: While informative consider copying the relevant section into this thread. A link-only-answer is not the best answer as links have a habit of disappearing (especially Magento documentation links!)

Comment: @philwinkle - Heh, yeah we've all been there. MagEbayVaporation (x_x) links galore.

Answer (score 4):

### Magento release patch SUPEE-6482 for fix for below issue in edition CE & EE

**For Magento Community Edition:**

- **Autoloaded File Inclusion in Magento SOAP API**
- **SSRF Vulnerability in WSDL File**

**For Magento Enterprise Edition**

- **Autoloaded File Inclusion in Magento SOAP API**
- **SSRF Vulnerability in WSDL File**
- **Cross-site Scripting Using Unvalidated Headers**

XSS in Gift Registry Search

Doing  change at class

- `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2`

**Changes at Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap**

```
             : $urlModel->getUrl('*/*/*');

         if ( $withAuth ) {
-            $phpAuthUser = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_USER', false);
-            $phpAuthPw = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_PW', false);
-            $scheme = $this->getController()->getRequest()->getScheme();
+            $phpAuthUser = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_USER', false));
+            $phpAuthPw = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getServer('PHP_AUTH_PW', false));
+            $scheme = rawurlencode($this->getController()->getRequest()->getScheme());

             if ($phpAuthUser && $phpAuthPw) {
                 $wsdlUrl = sprintf("%s://%s:%s@%s", $scheme, $phpAuthUser, $phpAuthPw,
```

change at **Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2**

```
     public function create($type, $set, $sku, $productData, $store = null)
     {
-        if (!$type || !$set || !$sku) {
+        if (!$type || !$set || !$sku || !is_object($productData)) {
             $this->_fault('data_invalid');
         }

@@ -243,6 +243,9 @@ class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2 extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api
      */
     protected function _prepareDataForSave ($product, $productData)
     {
+        if (!is_object($productData)) {
+            $this->_fault('data_invalid');
+        }
         if (property_exists($productData, 'website_ids') && is_array($productData->website_ids)) {
             $product->setWebsiteIds($productData->website_ids);
         }
```

See more at: <strike>http://www.amitbera.com/magento-security-patch-supee-6482/</strike>

Comment: Hi Amit Bera (@amit-bera),where can I get the patch SUPEE-6482 in the form of a separate zip of Magento 1.9.2.1 ?

Comment: @Andhi,magento 1.9.2.1   has been already included patch code at it code structure ,So you does not need to apply SUPEE-6482

Comment: @ Amit Bera, If still using Magento 1.9.1.0 whether to upgrade to 1.9.2.1? I mean, can only install the patch SUPEE-6428?

Comment: Note that the unvalidated header patch is not in the CE patches, the following files are not touched => `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml` are among the missing. Maybe we should change the question at the top to read: Magento security patch SUPEE-6482, What **isn't** patched?

Comment: @ Amit Bera, sorry, has been added by Magento at Added Aug 4, 2015 in https://www.magentocommerce.com/download : Download -> Magento Community Edition Patches -> SUPEE-6482

Comment: and this is How to install SUPEE-6482 without SSH http://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6482-without-ssh/

Answer (score 2):

This patch, like other recent patches, contains a lot of copy, license, and typo fixes. It also introduces a few typos from what I have seen.

The actual security patch part appears to address user input sanitization for 4 different potential attacks.